# How to create a json query in with any() in Breezejs

Tags: json, odata, breeze

I am trying to use this json predicate in Breeze:

```
predicate.push({
        or: [
            { not: { relocationStates: { any: {} } } },
            { relocationStates: { any: { "state.id": { "eq": 11 } } } }
        ]
    });
```

The purpose of not: {relocationStates: { any: {}}} is to include all items with empty list of relocationStates.

This should create a odata URL as follows:

```
$filter=(not RelocationStates/any()) or (RelocationStates/any(x1: (x1/State/Id eq 11)))
```

The above oData URL works fine, but breezejs is unable to create the URL and errors with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null
```

Is it possible to create a json query in Breezejs that will return all items where the list of submitems is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.  I've [created an issue for it](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/172) in Breeze.  You can expect a fix in the next release.

A crude workaround would be to put in some clause that is always true for relocationStates, e.g.

```
{ not: { relocationStates: { any: { "id": { "ne": null } } } } }
```